# What is the largest value one can get in game 2048 without new tiles appear

Tags: algorithms, summation, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

This is a simplified version of the famous game 2048. Given a 4x4 grids with some values chosen from {0, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048}. A value of 0 indicates that the position in the grid is unoccupied. What is the largest tile that can be produced by any (possible length-zero) sequence of moves (up, down, left,right) from the given game setup, if no new tiles were to be introduced to the grid?

For example, given

```
2 64 4 32
8 16 8 4
4 32 4 0
2 2 0 0
```

the answer is 128:

[image]

The problem can probably be solved by those AI algorithms ([minmax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax) for example), however, I guess that will definitely be an overkill. Is there any simpler algorithm to solve this?

Comment: If you don't mind occasional overestimation, you can just repeatedly merge like tiles assuming they can be brought together somehow. In your example, you can't acctually merge those two 8s, but the result is the same as if you could.

Comment: @ChuNan You might want to take a look at [this](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.04274.pdf) arxiv pdf